# A very strange String casting error

Tags: swift

I am creating array of views with this labels :

```
0.1, 0.2 , 0.3, 0.4 ...... 20
```

so:

```
        var time = 0.1
         for k in 0..<200
        {
              //........
            item.text = String(time) //*** here is the problem 

            time+=0.1
```

When it gets to **6** I get this on the label:

```
5.5 , 5.6 , 5.7 , 5.8 , 5.9, 5.99999,6.099999,6.199999
```

back to normal on `10.1 10.2 ,etc`

Whats so special about 6 ??  :)

Comment: I am on the hardware business :)

Comment: @AkshanshThakur Its 200 coz k increments in steps of 1 not 0.1

Comment: So , how you solve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to cast with a finite number of decimals, declare your `time` as a float and add it a float too:

```
var time = 0.1f
...

item.text = String(format:"%.1f", time)
time += 0.1f
```

Comment: K and Time has some other relation that I am not showing here.